# Octave: Unable to call a function from another .m file

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to integrate the function fx using Romberg Integration from x=0 to x=0.8 with a maximum of 10 iterations using the following two scripts:

RomScript.m:

```
function [rom_I,I,ea] = RomScript(a,b,fx,maxit,es)
maxit=10;
I=zeros(maxit+1,maxit+1);
es=0.001;
fx=@(x) 0.2 + 25*x - 200*x^2 + 675*x^3 - 900*x^4 + 400*x^5;
a=0;
b=0.8;

ea = 0;
iter=1;
while iter<=maxit+1
    for k=1:iter
        j=iter-k+1;
        if k==1
            n=2^(j-1);
            I(j,1)=TrapM(a,b,n,fx);
        else
            I(j,k) = (4^(k-1) * I(j+1,k-1) - I(j,k-1) )/ (4^(k-1) - 1);
        end
    end
    if iter>1
        ea = abs((I(1,iter) - I(2,iter-1)) / I(1,iter)) * 100;
        if ea < es 
            break;
        end
    end
    iter=iter+1;
end
```

TrapM.m:

```
function [TrapM,eapprox] = TrapM(a,b,n,fx);
h=(b-a)/n;
f=zeros(n+1,1);
for fi=1:n+1  
    f(fi)=fx(a+h*fi-h);
end
sum=f(1);

for i=2:size(f,1)-1
    sum=sum+2*f(i); 
end

sum=sum+f(end);
Trap=h*sum/2;

df = matlabFunction(diff(sym(fx),2));
df2= integral(df,a,b);
eapprox=df2/(b-a)*(b-a).^3/12/n.^2;
end
```

Whenever I run RomScript.m it gives this error:

```
error: 'TrapM' undefined near line 16 column 20
error: called from
    RomScript at line 16 column 19
```

From what I've seen from just messing around, it looks like Octave just doesn't understand that I'm referencing another .m file while MATLAB is able to do this.

Comment: Is `TrapM` on the search path? If you don't need to call `TrapM` from other functions, you can put it in the `RomScript.m` file, after the main function. It then becomes a private sub-function.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I should've mentioned that I've made sure they're both in the same folder that Octave is using as its "Current Directory." Could you elaborate on how to make it a private sub-function? I'm pretty new and my professor has done a really bad job at explaining how to use MATLAB/Octave in any capacity. Also, even if I don't need to call it from other functions, is there any reason why it doesn't work as is?

Comment: No, it should work. Try naming all your functions with lowercase letters only. Maybe it's an issue with a non-case-sensitive file system (Windows?). It could also be a typo (double-check your file name) or an issue with caching available functions. I don't know. This **should** work the way you're doing it.

Comment: Or maybe the problem is here: `function [TrapM,eapprox] = TrapM(a,b,n,fx);`. You're using `TrapM` as the name of the function and also as the return variable. Try calling `TrapM` directly from the Octave command prompt, see if you get any different error messages.

Comment: @CrisLuengo When I just type `TrapM` into the command prompt it says `TrapM is undefined near line 1 column 1`. I tried renaming the functions and file names to all-lowercase and that didn't help TrapM but interestingly it made RomScript also return the same message: `romscript is undefined near line 1 column 1.` Even after changing line 1 of TrapM to `function [trap,eapprox] = TrapM(a,b,n,fx);` Still just get `error: 'trapm' undefined near line 16 column 20
error: called from
    RomScript at line 16 column 19`

Comment: It says "`trapm` undefined"? So it's looking for a function `trapm`, not `TrapM`? If your file is called `trapm.m`, then your function name is `trapm`, independent of what you have in your `function...` line.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Well, I had changed `TrapM` in line 16 of RomScript to be lowercase to match the file name when I made it lowercase, but it seems like my Octave is incapable of recognizing lowercase file/function names. I've retyped the file and function names and I'm 100% sure they match and I'm still getting the same error. Maybe I need an Octave Package to be able to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: No, that should certainly not be necessary. Try restarting Octave, maybe it'll help. :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo Oddly enough I think that worked. Now it's just saying I need the symbolic package to be able to use the sym function in line 16 of TrapM. Thanks for your help! Very dumb that the program didn't want to work correctly until it was restarted. I'll have to keep that in mind this semester.